# Meu HTML nao carrega imagem

Tags: html

Eu boto o src mas o VS code não reconhece:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste JavaScript</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Acenda a lampada</h1>
        <img src="_imagens/lampada-apagada.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boas-vindas. Não duplique perguntas, siga as orientações na pergunta original para melhorar a [publicação](/q/589699/3635). Os comentários foram bloqueados na publicação atual, se precisar comentar, faça na pergunta original.